# Question on proof of rank nullity theorem on Wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra

In the first proof at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

In order to write $|T(S)| = n - k$ in the last line of the proof, I believe we need to know each of the $n-k$ images of $S$ under $T$ are distinct. How do we know that? Where is that demonstrated in the proof?

If that fact is indeed missing, how would I show it. All I can think of is it is a consequence of the linear independence of $T(S)$, but I cannot see how to proceed from there.

Comment: What are the objects $S$ and $T$?

Comment: T:V→W is a linear map and S is the extension of the kernel of T to a basis of V, by the Steinitz exchange. T(S) is then a basis of the image T(V).

Comment: If there were two such vectors in S which mapped to the same element through T, say $T(v_i) = T(v_j)$ then we would have that $v_i-v_j$ is in the kernel and is hence in the span of $\mathcal{K}$. But $\mathcal{S} \cup \mathcal{K}$ is supposed to be a basis of V.

Comment: That's it, I see now! Thank you.